# How to determine freeze/unfreeze status of a filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, freeze, xfs, fsfreeze

I use `xfs_freeze` to freeze and unfreeze my xfs filesystem:

```
xfs_freeze -f /blahblah

xfs_freeze -u /blahblah
```

After I run the unfreeze command I want to make sure that the filesystem is not frozen for sure. This command does not return any value or message.

I know I can try remounting the filesystem but that one is not full-proof.

Also if I run the unfreeze command again on an unfrozen filesystem I will get something like this:

```
xfs_freeze: cannot unfreeze filesystem mounted at /blahblah: Invalid
argument
```

This method is not fool-proof either because the message is not accurate.

Is there a command I can use that would tell me the freeze status of the filesystem, or is there a fool-proof method that I can use to determine this?

Any hint?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR:

While there is no direct way to query if a filesystem is frozen, you can abuse the fact that nested freezing attempts don't work. For example, I have an XFS filesystem mounted at /xfs_test:

```
[root@testvm1 ~]# mount | grep xfs_test
/dev/sdb1 on /xfs_test type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)

[root@testvm1 ~]# xfs_freeze -f /xfs_test/      # Initial freeze
[root@testvm1 ~]# echo $?
0

[root@testvm1 ~]# xfs_freeze -f /xfs_test/      # Subsequent freeze attempt
xfs_freeze: cannot freeze filesystem at /xfs_test/: Device or resource busy
[root@testvm1 ~]# echo $?
1
```

The same analogy works for un-freezing or thawing the filesystem:

```
[root@testvm1 ~]# xfs_freeze -u /xfs_test/      # Same filesystem, currently frozen
[root@testvm1 ~]# echo $?
0

[root@testvm1 ~]# xfs_freeze -u /xfs_test/      # Thawed filesystem
xfs_freeze: cannot unfreeze filesystem mounted at /xfs_test/: Invalid argument
[root@testvm1 ~]# echo $?
1
```

---

I had to do some digging to find out if the frozen/thawed state query was possible. Although the technical details were a little beyond my understanding, this is what I have put together.

Freezing and thawing a filesystem was a feature initially built for XFS. It was eventually brought forward to the Linux kernel, allowing the functionality to work for other filesystems as well. As [this LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/287435/) explains:

> Takashi Sato proposes taking an XFS-specific feature and moving it
>   into the filesystem code. The patch would provide an ioctl() for
>   suspending write access to a filesystem, freezing, along with a
>   thawing option to resume writes.
>
> ...
>
> Essentially the patch just exports the freeze_bdev() kernel function
>   in a user accessible way.freeze_bdev() locks a file system into a
>   consistent state by flushing  the superblock and syncing the device.
>   The patch also adds tracking of the frozen state to the struct
>   block_device state field.

At this point, nested freezing and thawing were possible. As I understand it, a counter variable in the code kept track of the nested freezing and thawing attempts. The variable would increment when freezing, and decrement when thawing. Only when the counter was 0 would the filesystem actually thaw.

After that, I found this patch discussion from 2016, which is about adding a new ioctl call to query the filesystem's state: [fs: add the FIGETFROZEN ioctl call](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/8832301/). As far as I can tell, this patch has not been merged into the kernel.

The patch discussion provided a few key points:

> And, besides, polling for frozenness from userspace is inherently racy
>   - by the time the syscall returns, the information may be incorrect, so you can't rely on it for decision making purposes in userspace.

And then:

> I [sic] quick dig shows nesting was intentionally broken more than 5
>   years ago in making the freeze ioctl work on btrfs.

This led me to the, ahem, solution shown above.

---

Yet another possibility is covered in [this answer over at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10096699/6216002). If you try to remount a filesystem which is frozen, the attempt will fail with a 'device is busy' error. The mount could also be busy for a number of other reasons, so this solution is admittedly not fool-proof.

Comment: While the mount could be busy for a number of other reasons, the filesystem being frozen is about one of the only ones that most people are likely to encounter that will cause a `mount -o remount` to fail with `-EBUSY`.

Comment: @kaptan Much appreciated. If my answer works for you, please do remember to upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: @Haxiel I have already upvoted. Let me implement your solution and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to write your own command that will check.

```
#!/bin/bash

function touchFs() {
    echo "mp: $1";
    touch "$1/frzn-5tst";
    if [ -f "$1/frzn-5tst" ]; then
            rm "$1/frzn-5tst" &> /dev/null;
    fi
}

function usage() {
    echo "$0 <mountpoint>";
    exit 1;
}

if [ -z $1 ]; then
   usage;
fi

touchFs $1&
ppid=$!;
state=`ps -o s= -p $ppid`;

if [ -z "$state" ]; then
    echo "device is unfrozen";
elif [ "$state" == "S" ]; then
    echo "device is frozen";
fi
```